# How to exit from a jQuery function implementation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet of code. I want some code to run during the 'change' event when clicking on a "select" input field. If the value of the option selected is zero, I would like to abort and not execute the remaining code. Here is the snippet :

```
$select.on('change',function(){
                        var newYear = this.value;
                        if(this.value === 0){
                            studentDiv.hide();
                            //I would like to return from here,and not execute any remaining code..
                        }else{
```

So how do I "return" from the the spot where I put the comment ? Typing `return;` doesn't seem to do anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like there might be more to this question because you answered it in your comment.

```
return;
```

Comment: That didn't work - I tried return and it executed the code after the if block anyway....

Comment: Then you are not executing the code you think you are executing. The value is probably a string instead of a number making your === false